# How to refresh Mysql connection?

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have a program using Python + python mysql connector + Mysql which is installed in a network and uses the same database. How do I refresh a connection without restarting the program on other Machines?

The Program is installed in more than one Machine and connects to the same Mysql database which is located on a Server. The program is working properly, but,
when a new data is entered or modified "SQL INSERT, UPDATE.... Statments" from one machine is not reflected in all other Machines until the program is restarted, which means that a new connection is necessary to show the new database data.

So, I would like to know how to refresh the connection without restarting the program on other machines.

## Here is the sample Connection code:

```
import mysql.connector as mc

conn = mc.connect(host='host', user='user', passwd='passw', db='db_name', port=port_number)

cur = conn.cursor()
```

## How to refresh This Connection while the program is running?

Answer (score 1):

closing and reopening connection may also solve your problem,
see following example in loop

```
import mysql.connector as mc

conn = mc.connect(host='host', user='user', passwd='passw', db='db_name', port=port_number)

while True:
    # check if youre connected, if not, connect again
    if (conn.is_connected() == False):
        conn = mc.connect(host='host', user='user', passwd='passw', db='db_name', port=port_number)

    cur = conn.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO db_name.myTable (name) VALUES (%(val)s);"
    val = {'val':"Slim Shady"}
    cur.execute(sql,val)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: mysql-connector-python has cmd_refresh() method which refreshes the connection and fetchs the most recent data, so to refresh it I used conn.cmd_refresh(1). Thanks for your answer and sorry for later comment.

Answer (score 0):

After inserting or updating, you should do a commit to make sure all data it's writed to the DB. Then it will be visible for everyone:

```
conn.commit()
```